# Apache/Passenger rufus cron job not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cron, passenger, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rails app running on Apache/Passenger.  I have a rufus cron job that runs in the background and sends out notifications via email.  When I am running the app in development on the WEBrick server, the emails are sent like they are supposed to be sent.  When I start up the app in production on Apache/Passenger, then the emails dont get sent.  The class doing the work is in config/initializers/task_scheduler.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'

Rails.logger.info "Starting the scheduler"

## to start scheduler
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new


## Every day at 6 AM, send email for projects that haven't been updated in 14 days
Rails.logger.info "Adding the Stale Email job to the scheduler"
scheduler.cron("* * * * *") do
  Rails.logger.info "Running every minute"
  projects = Project.stale
  projects.each do |project|
    Rails.logger.info "Inside the loop"
    days = (Time.now - project.updated_at).to_i / 1.day
    ProjectMailer.stale(Jetway::Application.config.stale_email, project, days).deliver
    Rails.logger.info "Sent stale email for project #{project.name}; it's #{days} days stale."
  end
end
```

Right now it is running every minute, so I can debug.  Here is my log file output.

```
Started GET "/assets/availity_spinner.gif" for 99.44.242.76 at 2012-06-23 21:46:28 -0400
Served asset /availity_spinner.gif - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
Starting the scheduler
Adding the Stale Email job to the scheduler
```

You can see the log statement and how far we get into the code.  I have read in blogs that Passenger kills threads, specifically around cron jobs.  I am stuck and trying to get a direction to figure out this issue.  Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Add the below lines to your apache2 config and restart your apache2 server

```
RailsAppSpawnerIdleTime 0
PassengerMinInstances 1
```