# rufus scheduler not running in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, scheduled-tasks, passenger

I have a rails server running under nginx & passenger. My `sheduler.rb` looks like this

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'
my_awesome_job = Rufus::Scheduler.new

my_awesome_job.cron '59 23 * * *' do
    #do something
end
```

Everything works fine if I set the job for the next 2-3 minutes (for test). But this one, as I need it in production, does not start at 23:59 every day. I don't know where is the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check your crontab list on the server? You can do it using this command 'crontab -l'

Comment: I don't have a crontab. I thought I don't need it... It looks I haven't read the documentation very well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, this problem is caused by the Rufus scheduler background thread being terminated after Phusion Passenger spawns a child process as part of the smart spawning method.

Read [Spawning methods explained](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#spawning_methods_explained).
The specific issue you're suffering from is probably [Smart spawning caveat #2: the need to revive threads](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_smart_spawning_caveat_2_the_need_to_revive_threads).

You need to revive the Rufus scheduler thread using the mechanism in the documentation. I'm not exactly sure which API call you need to make, so maybe you can ask the Rufus scheduler authors.

Alternatively, you can use the 'direct' spawning method. It's less efficient but it avoids compatibility issues like this.

Comment: Looks too complicated for me. I shall seek for other, more simple approach. Maybe [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Comment: When it comes to the execution model (e.g. the use threads), whenever is not fundamentally different from rufus-scheduler, and you are likely to experience the same issues there. The easiest way for you to solve this is by using the 'direct' spawning method in Passenger.

Comment: I am using passenger 5 standalone installation, where do I have to set passenger_spawn_method: direct  ?

Comment: @techspartans Pass the `--spawn-method direct` command line parameter to Passenger Standalone.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174563/apache-passenger-rufus-cron-job-not-working)

I've added these two lines in `nginx.conf` (after `passenger_enabled on;`):

```
    rails_app_spawner_idle_time 0;
    passenger_min_instances 1;
```

That keeps one passenger thread active.

Comment: "passenger start --spawn-method direct" can you help solve this issue