# Rufus Scheduler not running in production Nginx/Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger, rufus-scheduler

I have a Rails app running on Nginx/Passenger. It has a rufus-scheduler cron job that runs in the background and sends out notifications via email.

When I start up the app in production on Nginx/Passenger, the emails don't get sent. In the production logs it doesn't show any logs for rufus-scheduler.

I'm stuck in this problem. Not able to debug the scheduler.

But after reading some issues & articles, I am sure that scheduler thread is kill on production by passenger.

Code snippet:

## Example:

```
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler::singleton

scheduler.cron '0 12 * * *' do
  puts "alert scheduler called at"
  puts Time.now
  system("rake trigger:email RAILS_ENV=production")
end
```

Kindly help me on the conf for the passenger/nginx that allow the scheduler thread to run & trigger the mails.

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27980050/rufus-scheduler-not-running-in-production

Comment: duplicates https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler/issues/235

Comment: If you don't add more details to your question (for example your passenger configuration), then nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I have added the code example, is their any thing wrong in implementation.

Comment: I found out Rufus Thread is in sleep state always , is the a reason??

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this in passanger config block

passenger_spawn_method direct;

Comment: Or you can do it directly passenger start --spawn-method direct

Comment: Thanks Keval , it already been added still it's not working any other reason or configuration